# Enviar datos a un controlador Laravel con AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma web para una IPS con **Laravel 5.4** y **PostgreSQL 9.6**.
El problema que tengo es el siguiente: en el formulario de registro de pacientes deseo que al momento de perder el foco en el input que captura el numero de identificación, la aplicación mediante **Ajax** busque en la base de datos si ese numero de identificación ya existe para bloquear el botón de registro si el caso es afirmativo.

La ruta que se supone debe responder a la solicitud es la siguiente:

```
Route::post('/pnt/isexist', array('as' => 'pntisexist', 'uses' => 'PacienteController@isExist2'));
```

También lo he intentado con la siguiente ruta y tampoco me funciona:

```
Route::post('/pntisexist', function(){
$paciente = DB::select("SELECT NROUSR FROM LESUSR WHERE TPOPRS = 'PNT' AND NRIPRS = :NRIPRS", ['NRIPRS'=>$nriprs]);

return Response::json(array()); });
```

Mi archivo Javascript es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('#nriprs').blur(function(){

    var nriprs = $('#nriprs').val();
    //var dir = "http://lesoft.com/cif/public/pnt/isexist/" + nriprs; -> FORMA 1
    //var dir = "/pnt/isexist/"; -> FORMA 2
    //var dir = "{{route('pntisexist')}}"; -> FORMA 3
    //var dir = "{{url('pnt/isexist')}}"; -> FORMA 4 
    //var token =  $('input[name=_token]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "pntisexist",
        //headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token}, 
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { nriprs : nriprs },           
        beforeSend : function(){

        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.result != 'true') {
                alert('El paciente ya existe: ' + data.paciente);

            } 
        }
    });

});     
});
```

El problema radica realmente en que en el archivo Javascript nunca me reconoce la ruta como la pongo. Lo he intentado de varias maneras (he dejado las formas como lo he intentado en los comentarios del código) y nunca me funciona ninguna de manera que el navegador lanza el error 404 indicando que la ruta no existe.

Comment: Hola, ¿te valió la respuesta? ¿necesitas más información?

Answer (score 1):

Si defines la ruta de esta forma (es lo mismo que haces pero un poco más organizado):

```
Route::post('/pnt/isexist', 'PacienteController@isExist2')->name('pntisexist');
```

Debería funcionarte el llamado ajax usando el nombre de la ruta (en blade):

```
$.ajax({
    url: {{ route('pntisexist') }}, 
    method: 'post',
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco tuve que hacer algo parecido y lo que opté por hacer es usar `laroute` que es una librería en `javascript` que te permite "usar" las rutas de `Laravel`.

https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute

De este modo no tienes porque usar blade para `route()` si no que puedes seguir usando el documento como `javascript` pudiéndolo compilar con el resto de código `javascript`.